# receive xml file from software using java socket

Tags: java

I am trying to learn data from software using socket Java. In API they says that software send XML file like array of byte.

How I can parse xml file knowing that When I try to read from this socket using readline (so I can just echo my own sent message) my program hangs and won't return.

Comment: Non-blocking socket ?

Comment: XML not necessarily contains a line-ending; first try reading byte wise.

Comment: thank you for your answer, the problem is that I do not know the size of the information sent

Comment: Post your code, so that we can better understand the problem.

Comment: All the XML parser APIs take an `InputStream` or a `Reader.` You don't have any need to assume lines.